# Node.js loading external stylesheets from Jade, inconsistent path

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, path, pug

I am developing a nodejs application using the Jade template engine.

Inside my main("/") layout I have the following code that loads external CSS in my public path.

```
link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/styles.css')
...
```

there are multiple lines of external javascript and css files to be loaded.

However, When I have to load it from my /users/profile jade template the link is broken.

It says

```
GET http://localhost:3000/users/javascripts/underscore.js 404 (Not Found)
```

Is there a way to have a set of links that works in all of my Jade template so I don't have to manually redefine them everytime?

Thanks in advance,
Dennis

Comment: What does your server code look like?

Comment: Hard to say without the server code, but possibly you want to look at something like passing the css path into your template rendering function as a json value and setting it dynamically pre-render based on your route path with a little wrapper function or something every time you instantiate a route.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using `express` do it like this:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

`link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/styles.css')` this will make following http request: `GET http://localhost:3000/stylesheets/styles.css` and express will look for the file in directory: `~/public/stylesheets/styles.css`

Comment: Thank you so much. Finally worked. Saved me alot of time